# Localization of Windows Pathname in Python or PyQT

Tags: python, windows, path, pyqt, os.walk

I seaching now some days for a solution but can't find anything... I hope you can help.

I need the translated windows path in python.

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Calculator.lnk
```

is in Windows Explorer on german Systems:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Startmenü\Programme\Zubehör\Rechner.lnk
```

I need this translated Path/File name in Python or PyQT - If I use e.g. `os.walk()` it gives me real (untranslated) file names back - This is correct for most usage but in my special case I need the translated file/folder names...

Thank you very much

Comment: what do you mean by translated, translated to English?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows API for this is [SHGetLocalizedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This is a fairly new function (Windows Vista onwards), and so it does not seem to be currently available in [PyWin32](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/index.html). However, you can always wrap the function yourself using the [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/release/3.3.3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) module if there's not a ready-made solution available.